# categories in questions algorithm

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web-applications, logic

**Situation**
I'm a learner and im building a webapp in which people can login and ask/answer questions, sort of like quora.

**Problem**
I want the questions to be asked in perticular categories like..funny,tech,news,etc. and each questions can have multiple categories. So Im having a difficulty to desing a database based on this.

**Possible Solution**
My each question will have a questionid, unique and i can have a whole another table just for categories -> (questionid,category) which may have multiple entries per questionid. But is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each question can have multiple categories and each category can have multiple questions;Like this,

> CATEGORY_TABLE
>       -categoryId(PK)
>       -categoryName
>
> QUESTION_TABLE
>       -questionId(PK)
>       -question
>
> QUESTION_CATEGORY_TABLE
>       -questionId(PK)
>       -categoryId(PK)

I guess this is what you have suggested as a solution right?

Comment: but the thing is...the category table may get buffed up with maybe thousands of rows. Can it handle it?

Comment: category table or category_question table?

Comment: category_question table

Comment: Yeah that can be happen with the time but this is a normalized design. What you can do is may be trigger a procedure and break the table to separate tables according to the category they are in periodically. But i;m not that sure about it. May be you can look into indexing